# Personalized ::selection not working when using ::first-letter in CSS

Tags: css

I'm learning the basics of CSS right now and I found something weird on my test page. I was writing down the use of `::first-letter` and `::first-line` and just out of habit I select it all. For some reason when selecting the first word my `::selection` personalization was absent. Even weirder, it was just that one letter. For a second I thought it might be because I set the font-weight to bold, but other bold letters worked just fine.

```css
::selection{
    background-color: #8ebacc;
    color: black;
}

#first::first-letter{
    font-size: 30px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#first::first-line{
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p id="first">Here I wrote a lot of text. This first line is very fancy, and even fancier is the first letter. This is to give some emphasis to everything there, to establish that that is indeed the first line of this paragraph. </p>
```

What's going on? How can I fix it?

Comment: It works fine. The ::selection is being applied the the letter `H` whats your expected output please ?

Comment: Did you run it? The color of the background changes and so does the letter color.

Comment: So you do NOT want that H to be selected or have a background at all ? when you select the rest of the text ? Am i right ?

Comment: No not at all! I think we are getting different results. You see, when i select the whole line the H has the default ::selection settings. All of the other letters have my background-color: #8ebacc; change except H. Do you have the same result?

Comment: This is what i have : https://jsfiddle.net/a85nqjdp/3/

Comment: Dont you see that the H is blue and everything else is red?

Comment: So what do you want ? what is your expected output (in simple words)? Your question is not clear. You are mixing up things.

Comment: My expected output is for ALL the letters to be red

Comment: Thats easily understandable now. I will do some changes and explain what going on.

Comment: Are you using chrome ?

Comment: Yes, i am using chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `::first-letter` with :`:selection` in not working in chrome. Its a `known bug` which is raised with chrome dev already and is not fixed just yet.

If you can use `firefox` you can consider using `::mox-selection` and that should work fine in Mozilla firefox.

> You can follow the developments and update: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17528

Comment: @DefaultPeak You are welcome. Hoping that there is fix for it soon.