# drop cap selection color is different as of other

Tags: html, css, selection, paragraph

I have this Simple code

```css
.dropCaps:first-letter {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: calc(110% + 2.85vw);
  line-height: calc(110% + .2vw);
}

::selection {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<p class="dropCaps">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vitae vehicula leo.</p>
```

When I highlight the Full text, the `selection` style is applied to my `<p>` tag but the `selection` style doesn't work on the first letter which is a `dropped capital`

[image: See this]

Why is there this error? and how do I fix it ?

Update:
I am Using Brave Browser

Comment: Does this answer your question? [::selection not working when using :first-letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63083682/personalized-selection-not-working-when-using-first-letter-in-css)

Comment: This is a known chrome issue and there is no fix at this time

Comment: Nope, it doesn't